# What's name of this font which I can't find on what the font?

Tags: fonts, typefaces, serif

Quick question, I couldn't find the name of this font even on WhatTheFont.

Here's an image:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a variant of Britannic Bold. I think that comes with Windows; perhaps it's included in some software. The image you have is condensed a little.

[image: Britannic Bold]

Comment: Thanks. Is there any condensed alternative of this font or my image condensed?

Comment: @Ferdi Knowing the name, you can search for condensed versions just as well as I can. But the tails of `r` and `a` and the angle of the ascender on `t`  lead me to believe that it's simply compressed digitally.